How to upgrade from CUDA 11.5 to CUDA 12?
I am in stuck with CUDA 11.5 on my Ubuntu 22 running a RTX 4000.
I want to upgrade from 11.5 to 12 as many dev-libraries require this nowadays.
However, I can't bring it up.
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-12-6

I did this, but nvcc --version still shows
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0

Any ideas?

What does type -a nvcc show? And, if it shows you a path, what does dpkg -S that_path show?
